# Passing arguments to remote script from local script using except

Tags: ssh, expect

Hello Im newbie to Expect scripting. Im trying to call remote script using ssh spawn and passing commandline arguments to the remote script.But in remote script im getting null values. Please help to solve this issue. Is the problem with passing the arguments in except script?

**Local Expect script**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set hana_schema [lindex $argv 1]
set table [lindex $argv 2]
set condition [lindex $argv 3]
set yyyymm [lindex $argv 4]
set targetdir [lindex $argv 5]
set split [lindex $argv 6]
set timeout 120
set ip XXXX.XXX.XX.XX
set user name
set password pass
set script /path-to-script/test.sh
# here I spawn a shell that will run ssh and redirect the script to ssh's

spawn sh -c "ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $user@$ip bash $hana_schema $table $condition $yyyymm $targetdir $split < $script" "$hana_schema" "$table" "$condition" "$yyyymm" "$targetdir" "$split"
expect "Password:"
send "$password\r"

# and just wait for the script to finish
expect eof
```

**Remote script test.sh**

```
hana_schema=$1
table=$2
condition=$3
yyyymm=$4
targetdir=$5
split=$6
echo "$hana_schema"
echo "$table"
echo "$condition"
echo "$yyyymm"
echo "$targetdir"
echo "$split"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you're just passing the expect scripts parameters through to the remote script untouched. There's really no point saving them in separate variables. Also wrapping the ssh call with sh is not needed. I'd do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 120
set ip XXXX.XXX.XX.XX
set user name
set password pass
set ssh_opts {-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no}
set script /path-to-script/test.sh

spawn ssh {*}$ssh_opts $user@$ip bash $script {*}$argv

expect "Password:"
send "$password\r"
expect eof
```

The `{*}` syntax expands a list into its individual elements. See http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm

Comment: Thanks @Glenn Jackman. It passing the arguments. And quick doubt like by using spawn ssh how to login as root.

Comment: The command line arguments are stored in the global `$argv` list, so you could do `myproc $argv` to pass a single list, or `myproc {*}$argv` to pass all of the individual elements, or you could call myproc with no args and inside it do `proc myproc {} { global argv; foreach arg $argv {...`

Comment: Im getting following error while passing the arguments to the procdure wrong # args: should be "auto"
    while executing
"auto {*}argv"
    (file "./expect_test.sh" line 16)